# Can I create vectors from DataFrame columns on the fly in RCpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a far fetched question about `Rcpp`, I tend to use a lot of `DataFrame` objects to create `xxxVector` within `C++` and export those back to `R`. Sometimes I have to deal with 10 columns that I have to define myself like :

```
export [[Rcpp::export]]
List myFunction(DataFrame df){
   NumericVector a = df["a"], b = df["b"], c = df["c"];
   IntegerVector a2 = df["a2"], b2 = df["b2"], c2 = df["c2"];
   CharacterVector a3 = df["a3"], b3 = df["b3"], c3 = df["c3"];

   const int N = df.nrows();
   LogicalVector out(N),out1(N);

   for(unsigned int i = 0; i<N; ++i){
      //here I do what I want to do
   }

   return(List::create(_["out"]=out, _["out1"]=out1));
}
```

If the declaration list is long with complex names declarations take ages. I could just not declare `a,b,c,...` and work with `df["a"],...` but that would be even longer.
My question is then (and It might very well be heresy) is there a way to automatically define those vector columns ? I thought that as we have the `DataFrame` which is a list of pointers to columns may be it would be possible to automate it...

Comment: So make the names shorter?

Comment: Can't really have variables of less than 1 character... :). But on the idea of automated declaration, is it even doable ?

Comment: Have you tried indexing by (shudder, not recommended) position?  Or use a hash function?  :-)

Comment: No... you might have lost me already but do you mean stuff like `df[i][j]` where `i` would be the place for say `b` and `j` would access the `j`th elem of vector ? If so, I could do this but I am reluctant to do it because that would make the code unreadable (even for myself)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like, if this were R code, you want to turn the dataframe into an "environment". I can't see any way to do anything similar in C++ -- the difference between an interpreted and a compiled language.

If you're just wanting to automate the generation of boilerplate code, you could try doing that in R. Something along the lines of

```
genDfBoilerplate <- function( coltypes, dfname="df" )
{
  ## coltypes is a named character vector with elements  "Integer", "Logical", 
  ##   "Character", etc.
  ## and names(coltypes) are the dataframe column names
  ## the name of the dataframe is dfname (default: df)
  bp = character(0)
  for( name in names(coltypes) )
  {
    decl <- sprintf('    const %sVector& %s(%s["%s"]);', coltypes[name], name, dfname, name)
    bp <- append(bp, decl)
  }
  paste(bp, sep="", collapse="\n")
}
```

For example:

```
> coltypes = c(a="Integer", b="Numeric")
> bp = genDfBoilerplate(coltypes)
> cat(bp)
    const IntegerVector& a(df["a"]);
    const NumericVector& b(df["b"]);
```

(I've declared the variables as const references for maximum efficiency. You can obviously modify this depending on the specifics of your function (eg if the dataframe is passed by reference and you want a local copy of a column in order to modify it.))

How you get the boilerplate into your Rcpp function code I leave to you; copy/paste is one solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was doubting of the possibility to do it, but as you can pass environment from `R` to `C++` I was hoping knowledgeable people could find a way... For you suggestion not sure the `reference` `IntegerVector&` is very usefull as `DataFrame`is a list of pointers alresy but the idea is nice I'll do this from now on

Comment: If df["a"] returns just a "smart pointer" then a reference won't make much difference; but it's the only way in general in C++ to ensure that a "deep" copy isn't made. If you prefer the value syntax just alter genDfBoilerplate to your liking.